# How to redirect a user to a specific activity in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

While Registering an account using Firebase auth I stored emails in 2 categories Teacher and Student. I add emails to Firestore 2 different categories Teacher and Student with `email` and `password`. When I login I want to check that email belongs to which category (Teacher or Student) how can I do that I tried the firestore query isequalsto but it didn't differentiate.

Here is my database

**Teacher**

[image]

**Student**

[image]

Any other possible solution?

**here is my code for login activity**

```
package com.example.dell.step;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button mRegbtn;
    private Button mloginbtn;
    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPassword;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private ProgressDialog mLoginDialog;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private CollectionReference collectionReference_I;
    private CollectionReference collectionReference_S;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //Progress Dialog

        mLoginDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        //FOr Toolbar

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.login_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login Account");


        mloginbtn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        mRegbtn = findViewById(R.id.login_reg_btn);

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        mRegbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent regIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(regIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });


        mloginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    mLoginDialog.setTitle("Login User");
                    mLoginDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we login to your account :)");
                    //it stops cancel Dialog when user touch on screen
                    mLoginDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    mLoginDialog.show();

                    login_user(email, password);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void login_user(final String email, final String password) {

        collectionReference_I = firebaseFirestore.collection("Teacher");
        collectionReference_S = firebaseFirestore.collection("Student");

        collectionReference_I.whereEqualTo("teacher_email", email).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            //Dismiss the progress Dialog
                            mLoginDialog.dismiss();


                            //user is registered
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome to Teacher Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                            finish();


                        } else {

                            mLoginDialog.hide();

                            //if user is not registered
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Cannot Log in Please check the form and try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    }
                });


            }
        });

        collectionReference_S.whereEqualTo("Student_email", email).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            //Dismiss the progress Dialog
                            mLoginDialog.dismiss();


                            //user is registered
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome to Student Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StudentMain.class);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                            finish();


                        } else {

                            mLoginDialog.hide();

                            //if user is not registered
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Cannot Log in Please check the form and try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    }
                });


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your database structure and what error/output you got with the current approach ?

Comment: i add images now check in the post kindly

Comment: So looking at your data structure and the explanation you gave,i think you just want to be able to differentiate whether this email is of teacher or not nothing else? Right? or is there something else i am missing?

Comment: @SabaNayab You have to put all users in a single table called `user` for example and add an attribute called `user_type` `TEACHER` or `STUDENT` then you will be able to do what you want with a single API(Query) call, Then if the email exists check user type else user not exist.

Comment: yes @MayurGajra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two different collections, one for each type of your users isn't quite a flexible solutions. Another more simpler solution might be:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
        |
        --- uid (document)
        |    |
        |    --- email: "student@email.com"
        |    |
        |    --- password: "********"
        |    |
        |    --- type: "student"
        |
        --- uid (document)
             |
             --- email: "teacher@email.com"
             |
             --- password: "********"
             |
             --- type: "teacher"
```

See, I have added the type of the user as a property of your user object. Now, to get a user based on the email address, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
Query query = usersRef.whereEqualTo("email", "student@email.com")
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String email = document.getString("email");
                String password = document.getString("password");
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Once the user is authenticated, to redirect the user to the corresponding activity, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
usersRef.document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                String type = document.getString("type");
                if(type.equals("student")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Student.class));
                } else if (type.equals("teacher")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Teacher.class));
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if I want to check email on the login page how can I do that in the above answer I have to redirect to the main page first then I check the user type

Comment: Do that in two stepts, first step get email and passwork and login and redirect both to the main page and then redirect each user to the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.myapplicationomostff

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_registy.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var myauth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")






    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener {
            var email =txtemaillogin.text.toString().trim()
            var password =txtpasslogin.text.toString().trim()
            userlogin(email,password)


            }



        btnregistry.setOnClickListener{


            var intent = Intent(this, chose::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }




        }

    private fun userlogin(email: String, password: String) {
        var query = usersRef.whereEqualTo("email",email)
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                for (document in task.getResult()!!) {
                    var email1 = document.getString("email").toString()
                    var password1 = document.getString("password").toString()
                    if(password1 == password
                        && email1 == email
                    ){
                        myauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email1, password1).addOnCompleteListener{
                            if(it.isSuccessful){

                                val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
                                if (uid != null) {
                                    usersRef.document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                            val document = task.result
                                            if (document != null) {
                                                if (document.exists()) {
                                                    val type = document.getString("type")
                                                    if (type == "doc") {
                                                        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,docpage::class.java))
                                                    } else if (type == "eng") {
                                                        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, engpage::class.java))
                                                    }else  if (type=="mos"){
                                                        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, chosepage::class.java))


                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }



                                Toast.makeText(this,"ok",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(this,"erorr",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"مش مسجل ف الموقع ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users is you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer.