# How do i retreive a document in firebase firestore android to match my particular login credentials

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase of this structure below

[Structure of my Firestore Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLVev.jpg)

It has two users namely a church admin and normal church user

For **Church Admin** this is the code for Registering New Church

```
public void onBoardChurchDetails(String church_name, String church_addr, String church_email, String church_leadName, String churchPhone, String church_icon, String churchDescr, String church_regStat, final String uid) {
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        rhemaCollRef = rChurchFireStore.collection("rhema_churches");
        rhemaHiveChurchSubClass = getRhemaHiveChurchSubClass();

        if (rhemaHiveChurchSubClass.checkChurchEmptyParams(church_icon, church_name, church_addr, churchPhone, church_email, church_leadName, churchDescr, church_regStat,uid) == 1) {

            rhemaHiveChurchModelClass = getChurchModelClass(church_name, church_addr, church_email, church_leadName, churchPhone, church_icon, churchDescr, church_regStat,uid);

            rhemaCollRef.document(church_name).set(rhemaHiveChurchModelClass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        try {
                            getAuto().getToast(c, " Congratulations you Just Registered a new Church", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                            intent  = new Intent(c, RhemaHiveChurchPortal.class);
                            bundle.putString("church_id", uid);

                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            clearChurchDetails();
                        }
                        catch(NullPointerException np){
                            getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + np.getLocalizedMessage(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                        startActivity(getAuto().newActivityStarter(c, RhemaHiveChurchPortal.class));
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + e.getLocalizedMessage(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                }
            });


        } else {

            getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops Seems we are missing out some data here", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();

        }

    } else {
        getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops Seems No Internet Service is connected", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
    }
}
```

For User Registration I have

```
 public void onBoardUserWithoutSocial(String fName, String lName, String gender, String userType, String dob, String regStat, String imgPath, String userEmail, String phone , String about, final String churchName, String branchName, String addr, String city, String country, String postalCode, final String uid) {
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        fstore = getFstore();
    fiReference = fstore.collection("rhema_churches");
    rhemaHiveUserSubClass = getRhemaHiveUserSubClass();

        if (rhemaHiveUserSubClass.checkEmptyParam(fName, lName, branchName, churchName, addr, country, city, dob, gender, postalCode, regStat, phone,  userType,imgPath,userEmail,about,uid) == 1) {
            rhemaHiveUserModelClass = getUserModelClass(fName,lName,gender,userType,dob,regStat, imgPath,userEmail,phone,about,churchName,branchName,addr,city,country,postalCode,uid);
            fiReference.document(churchName).collection("members_data").document(getFullName(fName,lName)).set(rhemaHiveUserModelClass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        try{
                        getAuto().getToast(c, "Congratulation You've onboarded sucessfully..",RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                            bundle.putString("user_id", uid);
                            bundle.putString("user_church",churchName);

                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        clearUserDetails();
                        }
                        catch(NullPointerException np){
                            getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + np.getLocalizedMessage(),RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        getAuto().getToast(c,RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(),RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();

                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + e.getLocalizedMessage(),RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                }
            });

        } else {
            getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops ! !..Seems we are missing out some of your details", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
        }
    }
    else{
        getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops ! !..Seems you need to put on your data", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
    }
}
```

When succesfully registered i want a normal user to be able to login after authentication using any of the providers such as Facebook, Twitter or google, his portal should retreive his personalized portal using a combination of uuid and phone number

for retrieve Church profile see the code below

```
public void retreiveChurchDetails(String id) throws NullPointerException{
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    FirebaseFirestore fS = getFStore();
    rhemaCollRef = fS.collection("rhema_churches");
    rhemaCollRef.whereEqualTo("church_uid", id ).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot  : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()){
                    church_name = documentSnapshot.getString("church_name");
                    church_email = documentSnapshot.getString("church_email");
                    church_phone = documentSnapshot.getString("church_phone");
                    church_pix_link = documentSnapshot.getString("church_pix");
                    getTextView(R.id.church_retr_name).setText(church_name);
                    getTextView(R.id.church_retr_email).setText(church_email);
                    getTextView(R.id.church_retr_phone).setText(church_phone);
                    ld_wt_gl(c,church_pix_link,44,44,getImg(R.id.church_retr_logg));

                }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            getAuto().getToast(c,RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + e.getLocalizedMessage(),RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
        }
    });
    }

    else{
        getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops ! !..Seems we need an internet connection for this", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
    }
}
```

My question is how do i retrieve user details knowing fully well that to get the user data u have to follow the structure of

rhema_churches = > church_name(needs to identify how to get this) = > document => members_data => user_data

Please refer to database structure attached above

Please kindly help me..

See what i tried anyway

```
 public void retrUserDet(final String uid, String church_name) throws NullPointerException{
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        FirebaseFirestore fS = getFStore();
        rhemaCollRef = fS.collection("rhema_churches");
        rhemaCollRef.document(church_name).collection("members_data").whereEqualTo("user_uid",uid).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().isEmpty()){
                    for(DocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()){
                        user_email = doc.getString("user_email");
                        user_name = doc.getString("user_fName") + doc.getString("user_lName");
                        user_phone = doc.getString("user_phone");
                        user_pix_link = doc.getString("user_pix");
                        getTex(R.id.user_retr_email).setText(user_email);
                        getTex(R.id.user_retr_name).setText(user_name);
                        getTex(R.id.user_retr_phone).setText(user_phone);
                        ld_wt_gl(c,user_pix_link,44,44,getImg(R.id.user_retr_logg));

                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This method above needs two parameters to carry out its query namely uid and churchName

This is the method i tried for retreiving churchName but its not working

```
  public String retrChurchName(String uid){
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        rhemaCollRef = rChurchFireStore.collection("rhema_churches");
        //rhemaCollRef.
        rhemaCollRef.whereEqualTo("uid",uid).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()
                )
                {
                    if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                        churchName = documentSnapshot.getString("church_name");
                    }

                    else{
                        getAuto().getToast(c,"Document doesnt exist", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                getAuto().getToast(c,RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + e.getLocalizedMessage(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
            }
        });

        return churchName;

    }

    else{
        getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + networkInfo.getExtraInfo(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655249/how-we-can-check-from-firestore-that-email-belongs-to-which-collection/55655868#55655868) might help.

Comment: I understood your implementation which is i should have a UID as the document before my collection which makes sense and makes it easy for querying..I'll try it out and see if it works..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve my issues and my code is running fine..All thanks to Alex Mamo

The first thing i had to do was to restructure my onboarding code for both church and user

**For Church i have**

```
  public void onBoardChurchDetails(String church_name, String church_addr, String church_email, String church_leadName, String churchPhone, String church_icon, String churchDescr, String church_regStat, final String uid, String userType) {
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        rhemaCollRef = rChurchFireStore.collection("rhema_churches");
        rhemaHiveChurchSubClass = getRhemaHiveChurchSubClass();

        if (rhemaHiveChurchSubClass.checkChurchEmptyParams(church_icon, church_name, church_addr, churchPhone, church_email, church_leadName, churchDescr, church_regStat, uid, userType) == 1) {

            rhemaHiveChurchModelClass = getChurchModelClass(church_name, church_addr, church_email, church_leadName, churchPhone, church_icon, churchDescr, church_regStat, uid, userType);

            rhemaCollRef.document(uid).set(rhemaHiveChurchModelClass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        try {
                            getAuto().getToast(c, " Congratulations you Just Registered a new Church", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();

                            bundle.putString("church_id", uid);

                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            //clearChurchDetails();
                        } catch (NullPointerException np) {
                            getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + np.getLocalizedMessage(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                        startActivity(getAuto().newActivityStarter(c, RhemaHiveChurchPortal.class));
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + e.getLocalizedMessage(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                }
            });


        } else {

            getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops Seems we are missing out some data here", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();

        }

    } else {
        getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops Seems No Internet Service is connected", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
    }
}
```

For User Onboarding I have

```
public void onBoardUserWithoutSocial(String fName, String lName, String gender, String userType, String dob, String regStat, String imgPath, String userEmail, String phone , String about, final String churchName, String branchName, String addr, String city, String country, String postalCode, final String uid) {
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        fstore = getFstore();
    fiReference = fstore.collection("rhema_churches");
    rhemaHiveUserSubClass = getRhemaHiveUserSubClass();

        if (rhemaHiveUserSubClass.checkEmptyParam(fName, lName, branchName, churchName, addr, country, city, dob, gender, postalCode, regStat, phone,  userType,imgPath,userEmail,about,uid) == 1) {
            rhemaHiveUserModelClass = getUserModelClass(fName,lName,gender,userType,dob,regStat, imgPath,userEmail,phone,about,churchName,branchName,addr,city,country,postalCode,uid);
            fiReference.document(uid).set(rhemaHiveUserModelClass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        try{
                        getAuto().getToast(c, "Congratulation You've onboarded sucessfully..",RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                            bundle.putString("user_id", uid);
                            bundle.putString("user_church",churchName);

                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        clearUserDetails();
                        }
                        catch(NullPointerException np){
                            getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + np.getLocalizedMessage(),RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        getAuto().getToast(c,RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(),RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();

                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + e.getLocalizedMessage(),RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
                }
            });

        } else {
            getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops ! !..Seems we are missing out some of your details", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
        }

    }




    else{
        getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops ! !..Seems you need to put on your data", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
    }
}
```

So instead of having a collection inside another collection.. I simply had a single collection as rhema_churches and then had an ID for every type of user..

See the structure below

[New DB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WViWF.jpg)

With this structure it becomes difficult to login with  more than one provider as each Provider you use is logged as the document id which is easy for retrieval

This is how the new query for User and Church now looks like

**For Church Query we have**

```
 public void retreiveChurchDetails(String id) throws NullPointerException {
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        FirebaseFirestore fS = getFStore();
        rhemaCollRef = fS.collection("rhema_churches");
        rhemaCollRef.whereEqualTo("church_uid", id).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                    church_name = documentSnapshot.getString("church_name");
                    church_email = documentSnapshot.getString("church_email");
                    church_phone = documentSnapshot.getString("church_phone");
                    church_pix_link = documentSnapshot.getString("church_pix");
                    getTextView(R.id.church_retr_name).setText(church_name);
                    getTextView(R.id.church_retr_email).setText(church_email);
                    getTextView(R.id.church_retr_phone).setText(church_phone);
                    ld_wt_gl(c, church_pix_link, 88, 88, getImg(R.id.church_retr_logg));

                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                getAuto().getToast(c, RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_GENERIC + e.getLocalizedMessage(), RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        getAuto().getToast(c, "Oops ! !..Seems we need an internet connection for this", RhemaHiveClassReferenceConstants.TOAST_SHORT_LEN).show();
    }


}
```

**And then for user query I have**

```
public void retrUserDet(final String uid) throws NullPointerException{
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        FirebaseFirestore fS = getFStore();
        rhemaCollRef = fS.collection("rhema_churches");
        rhemaCollRef.whereEqualTo("user_uid",uid).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().isEmpty()){
                    for(DocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()){
                        user_email = doc.getString("user_email");
                        user_fName  = doc.getString("user_fName");
                        user_lName = doc.getString("user_lName");

                        user_phone = doc.getString("user_phone");
                        user_pix_link = doc.getString("user_pix");
                        getTex(R.id.user_retr_email).setText(user_email);
                        getTex(R.id.user_retr_name).setText(retFullName(user_fName,user_lName));
                        getTex(R.id.user_retr_phone).setText(user_phone);
                        ld_wt_gl(c,user_pix_link,120,120,getImg(R.id.user_retr_logg));

                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The key take-away is never complicate your database structure too early..for any type of data that goes to my Firestore it has a usertype which can also help me in my filter

Thanks !