# Login with different Roles in Android Studio Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm kinda new to both Android Studio and Firebase. So basically I want to create a different login roles. One is for the Student and One is for the Admin.
So here's my Database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S45yd.png

**The database is only just a sample and will do hashing once the login system is functioning**

So here's my Login Button and every time I log in it's working and no Error Message

```
btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String user_id = userID.getText().toString() +"@gmail.com".trim();
                final String user_password = password.getText().toString().trim();

                fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_id,user_password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        checkUserAccessLevel(authResult.getUser().getUid());
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

So basically it's working. Everytime I hit the Login it'll pop up the toast "Logged in Successfuly"
but it doesn't intent the activity that is stored inside of my function CheckUserAccessLevel

```
private void checkUserAccessLevel(String uid) {
        DocumentReference reference = fStore.collection("Users").document(uid);
        reference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess: " + documentSnapshot.getData());
                // identify access user level

                if (documentSnapshot.getString("isAdmin") != null ){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "SuccessFully Logged In as Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WelcomeStudentActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
                if (documentSnapshot.getString("isStudent") != null){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "SuccessFully Logged In as Student", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ForgotPasswordActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

But if I'll put intent back to the intent inside the onSuccess function

```
public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WelcomeStudentActivity.class));
                    finish();
                        // checkUserAccessLevel(authResult.getUser().getUid());
                    }
```

and remove the CheckUserAccessLevel it will intent only the WelcomeStudentActivity Class or depends on what I put inside . Is there any way on how to fix this? I am really confused.

Comment: Please explain properly what you want to do when admin login and student login

Comment: I think this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655249/how-we-can-check-from-firestore-that-email-belongs-to-which-collection/55655868#55655868)** will help.