# How to redirect two types of users to different activity in Anroid studio using firebase auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

So I want to create student access with student emails and admin access with admin email. Stud email just unique numbers @ students.schoolname.com for e.g 123@students.schoolname.com, 321@students.schoolname.com. Admin is unqiue for example admin@gmail.com.

I want students to go to different activity when they sign in, and admin to go to another activity. I am currently using firebase authentication.

NOTE: I already have made this app, just adding extra features so sign-in works perfectly fine

I tried to approach the following way but didn't work out:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    
        String email = lEmail.getText() .toString() .trim();
        String password = lPassword.getText() .toString() .trim();
        fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password). addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
    
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged In Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if (!user.isEmailVerified()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Verify.class));
                    }
                    else {
                        FirebaseUser gettinguser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        String emailcheck = gettinguser.getEmail();
                        if (emailcheck.toString() == "admin@gmail.com"){
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admin.class)); }
                        else{
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You can achieve that either with the [Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities) or with [Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655249/how-we-can-check-from-firestore-that-email-belongs-to-which-collection/55655868#55655868).

Comment: You can check like this if (emailcheck.contains("@students")){redirect student activity} or else{admin activity}