# Hiding/making unaccessible features in android application according to user type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I am creating an Android application in which suppose there are 2 user types, userType1 & userType2. Now what I want is that only userType1 will see and be able to access the post button, and userType2 Can't see and or access it. So what is the best practice for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would be to implement [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and save user data, either in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) together with the user type. When you start the app, first you have to read the user type and then display the UI elements according to it. I have answered a question in which I have explained how to redirect the user according to its type to the corresponding activity. Here is how you can do that using Cloud Firestore:

- [How to redirect a user to a specific activity in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655249/how-we-can-check-from-firestore-that-email-belongs-to-which-collection/55655868#55655868)

Or using the Firebase Realtime Database:

- [How to redirect multiple types of users to their respective Activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895188/how-to-redirect-multiple-types-of-users-to-their-respective-activities)

The same mechanism can be used to hide/display a button. Don't also forget to secure your data using security rules.

Comment: Is it necessary to make different activities/fragments for different users? like I want everything to be the same just hide 1 button from userTpye2.

Comment: No, there is not. Those were just simple examples. You can use a single activity and display the UI elements according to the type of user. For example, for userType1 you can set the visibility of a button to GONE, and for userType2 set the visibility to VISIBLE.