# Can i use multiple apps on a single firebase database? Will it use same auth or different auth?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently developing multiple apps with Firebase and I have a doubt. I have a user and an admin. My problem is if I am using the same firebase database, will the user be able to sign up into Admin's app using his credentials or both app will have different authentication.  I don't want the user logging into the admin app with user credentials. If it is possible, what can I do to avoid it?

I haven't done trying it.

Comment: The question is unclear. Why would a user have the Admins login credentials? - that seems like a security issue.  Each user as their own login authentication info and Firebase account. Perhaps a review of the [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and the [Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) section would provide some understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use multiple apps on a single Firebase database?

Yes, you can.

> Will it use the same auth or a different auth?

If both apps are added to the same project, then the authentication will be the same for both projects. This means that the user can use the same account for both projects. This also means that both apps can write/read data to/from the same database.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict the Admin login to admin app and user login to user app. I want to write data between admin and user. So is there any way. ?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can [send the users to their corresponding screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655249/how-we-can-check-from-firestore-that-email-belongs-to-which-collection/55655868#55655868). Besides that, you can also consider using [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: yes i used roles for different users. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AlexMamo Is it also possible to use one single firestore db for many apps added to different projects?

Comment: @Angelo No, only within the same project.

Comment: @Angelo Did my answer/comment help?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in multiple ways

- Have a different collection to store the data of the admins and then check on the login if the email is present in the collection
- With the Rules of Firestore

Comment: I didn't get it. What rules of firestore. ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).