# How to know the type of the user before signing in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 types of users, admins and regular users. I understand that when a user signs up, a FirebaseUser object is created. I read the documentation, and I did not find any field in which I can store such information. I need somehow a boolean field called `admin` in which I can store `true` or `false`. I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655249/how-to-redirect-a-user-to-a-specific-activity-in-cloud-firestore/55655868#55655868) where it is said that we can save the type of the user in Firestore, but that means that I have to read the document first. And that costs.

Is there a way in which I know the type of the user before it signs in, so I can know to which activity to redirect the user without the need to read a Firestore document? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: "Is there a way in which I know the type of the user before it signs in" Firebase Authentication has no knowledge of a type of user, it merely handles the authentication part. If your app has types of users, it is your application that will need to provide the necessary information about what type of user is trying to sign up - e.g. by having a separate sign-up screen for each type of user, by having a separate app for each type of user, by having a list somewhere of the email addresses of each type of user, etc.

Comment: This topic has been covered extensively before and many of those approaches don't rely on Firestore (although they all need a way to know what the type of user is, as explained in my first comment). I recommend reading some of these previous [posts about types of users in Firebase](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+type+of+user) and trying to implement it. If you run into problems with a specific implementation, post back and it's more likely we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a solution using firebase real-time database.

```
 private void registerAccount(String name, String rank, String mobilePhone, String mail, String pass){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                      
                            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
                            Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                            userInfo.put("name", name);
                            userInfo.put("report", "off");
                            userInfo.put("email", mail);
                            userInfo.put("rank", rank);
                            userInfo.put("mobile", mobilePhone);
                            userInfo.put("userRole", "admin");
//can be role user, admin or others 
                            
                            myRef.child(mAuth.getUid()).setValue(userInfo)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                                        }
                                    });
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed."+task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not answering my question at all.

Comment: @JoanP. if you want more you can use Firebase admin which will give you the super user permission of your project. it's for only admin